# grouped data select rows and include rows before/after

Tags: r

I have a grouped data and I want to select a rows that fulfill a certain condition (works with code provided below), but I also want to include the row before and after the selected rows (so basically match row with criteria and then select row +1 row up +1 row down from the original dataset). The code below give me two rows per group those are the rows that match for my criteria. I now also want to include the rows before and after the selected rows.

I tried the following code, but the code line which would give me this output does not work:   desired_result[which(desired_result$Caffeinefactor == "yes") + c(-1:1), ] %>%

```
daf1 <- df %>% 
  setDT(df) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(PATIENT.ID) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(first_yes = cumsum(Caffeinefactor == "yes"), 
         last_no = (Caffeinefactor == "no") * row_number(), 
         last_no = ifelse(first_yes == 0, last_no, 0)) %>% 
  dplyr:: filter((first_yes == 1 & Caffeine >0) | last_no == max(last_no)) %>%
  desired_result[which(desired_result$Caffeinefactor == "yes") + c(-1:1), ] %>%
  dplyr::select(-first_yes, -last_no)
```

```
structure(list(PATIENT.ID = c(210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 
210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 
210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 221179L, 
221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 
221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 301705L, 
301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 
301705L), Caffeine = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 200L), Caffeinefactor = c("no", "no", 
"no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"), PULSE.WIDTH = c(0.5, 
0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    PATIENT.ID = c(210625L, 221179L, 301705L, 303926L, 309668L, 
    312580L, 313644L, 316332L, 326693L, 336204L, 337968L, 340160L, 
    341787L, 343627L, 346128L, 349800L, 351701L, 352235L, 354458L, 
    356470L, 357583L, 358002L, 358447L, 359628L, 861559L, 875452L, 
    876598L, 877257L, 877535L, 878250L, 878781L, 880014L, 880911L, 
    881002L, 881972L, 882667L, 883375L, 883799L, 884914L, 885233L, 
    885802L, 889623L, 891145L, 892464L, 893308L, 895449L), .rows = structure(list(
        1:17, 18:31, 32:46, 47:53, 54:61, 62:72, 73:95, 96:107, 
        108:131, 132:146, 147:165, 166:174, 175:186, 187:191, 
        192:203, 204:215, 216:227, 228:244, 245:263, 264:278, 
        279:290, 291:301, 302:313, 314:326, 327:350, 351:365, 
        366:376, 377:389, 390:399, 400:413, 414:424, 425:445, 
        446:453, 454:466, 467:477, 478:494, 495:508, 509:517, 
        518:524, 525:534, 535:554, 555:557, 558:573, 574:585, 
        586:593, 594:598), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -46L), .drop = TRUE), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe7f7002ee0>)
```

What the output looks like now without the code line ( desired_result[which(desired_result$Caffeinefactor == "yes") + c(-1:1), ])

| PATIENT.ID | Caffeinefactor | PULSE.WIDTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 210625L | no | output |
| 210625L | yes | output |
| 220909L | no | output |
| 220909L | yes | output |
| 301705L | no | output |
| 301705L | yes | output |

The output should look like this if one row is added before and after:

| PATIENT.ID | Caffeinefactor | PULSE.WIDTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 210625L | no | output |
| 210625L | no | output |
| 210625L | yes | output |
| 210625L | yes | output |
| 220909L | no | output |
| 220909L | yes | output |
| 220909L | yes | output |
| 301705L | no | output |
| 301705L | no | output |
| 301705L | yes | output |
| 301705L | yes | output |

... I put output for pulse with, because I do not know what the exact value would be

The original dataset has more that 90 columns and I also need to keep the values in these column. I do not want to duplicate the rows that the shown code selected.

Comment: Where is the column `Caffeine` in your data?

Comment: sorry, I included the column now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider creating a column to indicate which rows you wish to retain, and then `filter` the selected row, and use `lead` and `lag` to keep the rows before and after those selected rows?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  setDT(df) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT.ID) %>% 
  mutate(first_yes = cumsum(Caffeinefactor == "yes"), 
         last_no = (Caffeinefactor == "no") * row_number(), 
         last_no = ifelse(first_yes == 0, last_no, 0),
         select_row = (first_yes == 1 & Caffeine > 0) | last_no == max(last_no)) %>%
  filter(select_row | lag(select_row) | lead(select_row)) %>%
  select(-first_yes, -last_no, -select_row)
```

**Output**

```
   PATIENT.ID Caffeine Caffeinefactor PULSE.WIDTH row_id
        <int>    <int> <chr>                <dbl>  <int>
 1     210625        0 no                    0.75      3
 2     210625        0 no                    0.75      4
 3     210625      200 yes                   0.75      5
 4     210625      200 yes                   0.75      6
 5     221179        0 no                    1        25
 6     221179        0 no                    1        26
 7     221179      200 yes                   1        27
 8     221179      200 yes                   1        28
 9     301705        0 no                    0.5      36
10     301705        0 no                    0.5      37
11     301705      200 yes                   0.5      38
12     301705        0 no                    0.5      39
```